# Read csv file into n dimensional array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a data set from a Design of Experiments run in a CSV file.  Its basically an n-dimensional array in table form.

The CSV file is the output of a multivariable calculation.  Currently, the data set is 7 dimensions, but could be more.

I'm trying to read this data into an n-dimensional array in python so I can interpolate in the n-dimensional space.

Same of the data below:

```
var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,output1,output2,output3
1,1,1,1,1,777,888,999
1,1,1,1,2,777,888,999
1,1,1,1,3,777,888,999
1,1,1,2,1,777,888,999
1,1,1,2,2,777,888,999
1,1,1,2,3,777,888,999
1,1,2,1,1,777,888,999
1,1,2,1,2,777,888,999
1,1,2,1,3,777,888,999
1,1,2,2,1,777,888,999
1,1,2,2,2,777,888,999
1,1,2,2,3,777,888,999
1,2,1,1,1,777,888,999
1,2,1,1,2,777,888,999
1,2,1,1,3,777,888,999
1,2,1,2,1,777,888,999
1,2,1,2,2,777,888,999
1,2,1,2,3,777,888,999
1,2,2,1,1,777,888,999
1,2,2,1,2,777,888,999
1,2,2,1,3,777,888,999
1,2,2,2,1,777,888,999
1,2,2,2,2,777,888,999
1,2,2,2,3,777,888,999
2,1,1,1,1,777,888,999
2,1,1,1,2,777,888,999
2,1,1,1,3,777,888,999
2,1,1,2,1,777,888,999
2,1,1,2,2,777,888,999
2,1,1,2,3,777,888,999
2,1,2,1,1,777,888,999
2,1,2,1,2,777,888,999
2,1,2,1,3,777,888,999
2,1,2,2,1,777,888,999
2,1,2,2,2,777,888,999
2,1,2,2,3,777,888,999
2,2,1,1,1,777,888,999
2,2,1,1,2,777,888,999
2,2,1,1,3,777,888,999
2,2,1,2,1,777,888,999
2,2,1,2,2,777,888,999
2,2,1,2,3,777,888,999
2,2,2,1,1,777,888,999
2,2,2,1,2,777,888,999
2,2,2,1,3,777,888,999
2,2,2,2,1,777,888,999
2,2,2,2,2,777,888,999
2,2,2,2,3,777,888,999
```

Comment: Can you give a small example of your data?  It is a csv of `x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7` ?

Comment: Sounds like a job for pandas, although it's hard to tell with no data. You should also read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as SO is intended to help programmers with specific technical issues, not to write code to order.

Comment: At least as used in `numpy` a 7 dimensional array cannot be represented as a 2d csv table.  Give an example of the csv, and a clearer explanation of what you need to do with it.  My guess is that you have a 2d array with many 'rows' and 7 'columns', not a 7d array.

Comment: Reading a well formatted csv file is easy - just read a line, split on the delimiter, convert all elements of the resulting list to numbers and collect in a list of lists.

Comment: As a new member, you may want to read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: @James I have shared an example of the data

Comment: @hpaulj I have heard this type of data set referred to as a "nested table"

Comment: Your sample appears to have blocks of 7 numbers delimited with `,`, with space (or tab or nl?) separating the blocks.  If those blocks were on separate lines, `np.genfromtxt` could easily read them and give you a (n,7) array.  Or you could use the header names and get a structured array of shape (n,) and a compound dtype with 7 fields.

Comment: Viewed with edit your example shows multiple lines with 7 columns.  Try indenting as code.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

There's an example right there; it'll get you the values you want out of the csv file. You'll probably want to modify it to convert your values to integers. Something like the following:

```
import csv
data = []
with open('data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data.append([int(val) for val in row])
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do with the data after you read it in the pandas and numpy libraries might work well for you.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data = df.values
```

The data variable would contain an n-dimensional numpy array. Also numpy allows for vectored operations which could potential give you a large speed advantage for whatever operations you need to do on the array.

Answer (score 0):

copy-n-paste from an editor view of your post, I can load the data with:

```
In [10]: data=np.genfromtxt('stack42708781.txt',delimiter=',',dtype=int,skip_header=1)
In [11]: data[:5,:]
Out[11]: 
array([[  1,   1,   1,   1,   1, 777, 888, 999],
       [  1,   1,   1,   1,   2, 777, 888, 999],
       [  1,   1,   1,   1,   3, 777, 888, 999],
       [  1,   1,   1,   2,   1, 777, 888, 999],
       [  1,   1,   1,   2,   2, 777, 888, 999]])
In [12]: data.shape
Out[12]: (48, 8)
```

or

```
In [19]: data=np.genfromtxt('stack42708781.txt',delimiter=',',names=True,dtype=None)
In [20]: data.shape
Out[20]: (48,)
In [21]: data[:5]
Out[21]: 
array([(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 777, 888, 999), (1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 777, 888, 999),
       (1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 777, 888, 999), (1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 777, 888, 999),
       (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 777, 888, 999)], 
      dtype=[('var1', '<i4'), ('var2', '<i4'), ('var3', '<i4'), ('var4', '<i4'), ('var5', '<i4'), ('output1', '<i4'), ('output2', '<i4'), ('output3', '<i4')])
```